# How can I remove a node import from the resulting JS when compiling with tsc?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, tsc

I am trying to generate JS code with the following tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "es2016",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
    "lib": ["ES2019","dom"],                                        /* Specify a set of bundled library declaration files that describe the target runtime environment. */

    /* Modules */
    "module": "esnext",                                /* Specify what module code is generated. */
     "moduleResolution": "node",                       /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */
     "baseUrl": "./",                                  /* Specify the base directory to resolve non-relative module names. */

    /* JavaScript Support */
     "allowJs": true,                                  /* Allow JavaScript files to be a part of your program. Use the `checkJS` option to get errors from these files. */

    /* Emit */
     "outDir": "./dist/",                                   /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */
     "noEmit": true,                                   /* Disable emitting files from a compilation. */

    /* Interop Constraints */
     "isolatedModules": true,                          /* Ensure that each file can be safely transpiled without relying on other imports. */
     "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,             /* Allow 'import x from y' when a module doesn't have a default export. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` for type compatibility. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */

    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true,                                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */

    /* Completeness */
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/Container.js"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules/**/*", "dist/**/*","konva/*"],
}
```

This configuration generates one js file in the dist directory for each TS file, this way I can mantain the file structure.

The problem is that I need to import Konva lib from npm in order to use it, and when I compile I get this import in the JS files which need this lib:

```
import Konva from "konva"
```

This raises an error because it is not a valid path. Right now I have a python script removing this line from the resulting files, but I would like to remove it because it is an extra dependency just for removing one line.

When running the website it does not have any problem because I import Konva lib from CDN.

I am pretty new to TS and I don't know if it is possible to remove the import statement from npm modules or if I have to bundle everything together, any tip is welcome.

Thanks.